# Igraph Analysis No Data

Tags: python, csv, graph, igraph, analysis

We are using Igraph and python to analyse a huge graph and extract communities using walktrap as follow:

```
`dendrogram = gr.community_walktrap(weights=None,steps=1)
clusters = dendrogram.as_clustering()
membership = clusters.membership
writer = csv.writer(open("/root/output.csv", "wb"))
for name, membership in izip(gr.vs["name"], membership):
    writer.writerow([name, membership])`
```

The file is Ok when we have 100,000 node and 1M edge but when we launch the process on a bigger graph then the process finishes without any error but no file as output.

We also used the louvain algorithm known to handle large graph and we have the same issue.

Can you please help me ?

Thanks

Comment: how about printing sample data of clusters and dendrogram ? And I recommend using multi-level (i.e. fast unfolding) in huge graph, which is much more faster and sometimes better than step-1 walktrap.